# Connecting an AirPort Time Capsule to a router running a VPN

Tags: vpn, time-capsule

So, currently I have a TC connected via an Ethernet cable to my router. For reasons of where I am this router runs a VPN. Okay, so far so good. But the router with the VPN is not very stable for whatever reason (there could be a few here).  So I thought, could I run the router off the TC so that the TC became the primary network and those who needed the VPN could connect to that. Hopefully this would provide a more stable "base station" and only the VPN network would fall over from time to time?  I might also get faster back ups. Four MacBooks are using the TC for backup and 9 devices in total are using the wifi

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Only whether there was a flaw in this thinking and whether I would need to do anything extra to make this work like reserve some ip range for the VPN router to be able to allocate or the like?

Comment: It seems the TC device seems to be a wireless router, right? So then the question would have to be if it has a modem in.. and it looks like it doesn't http://www.apple.com/uk/airport-time-capsule/specs/    It has a WAN port not an ADSL or Cable modem port.

Comment: And with your non-TC router  as your main one, (nearer the wall), how did you connect your TC router to it? Did you turn off DHCP on one of them? Did you make the subnets the same? Did you turn off NAT on the TC? Did you make one IP .1 and the other .2 so that you could access the Interface?   (or .100 and .101?)

Comment: yes made the TC a bridge only

Comment: Yes, I think the questions point me in the right direction - I'll give it a go with the router with DHCP and NAT turned off first